# Filling text boxes with player names received from an array

Tags: objective-c

I'm currently trying to make the code of an app I'm developing a bit more efficient and easier to read. Basically what this does is after the user taps with two fingers (gesture) it retrieves a previously saved array from `NSUserDefaults` of player names, and fills in the 6 text boxes (tagged 6-11) on a table view with these names. If there isn't an existing array it'll use a default set of names.

I'm trying to reduce the length of a long `for`/`if` statement.  Any ideas for simplifying this code would be appreciated.

```
if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSMutableArray *names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"nameArray"]];
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
            UITableViewCell *cell = [playerTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
                if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
                    UITextField *txtField = (UITextField *)view;
                    if (txtField.tag == 6) {
                        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"customNames"]) {
                            txtField.text = [names objectAtIndex:0]; }
                        else {
                            txtField.text = @"Peter";
                        }
                    }
                    if (txtField.tag == 7) {
                        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"customNames"]) {
                            txtField.text = [names objectAtIndex:1]; }
                        else {
                            txtField.text = @"Julia";
                        }
                    }
                    if (txtField.tag == 8) {
                        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"customNames"]) {
                            txtField.text = [names objectAtIndex:2]; }
                        else {
                            txtField.text = @"Durgan";
                        }
                    }
                    if (txtField.tag == 9) {
                        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"customNames"]) {
                            txtField.text = [names objectAtIndex:3]; }
                        else {
                            txtField.text = @"Bob";
                        }
                    }
                    if (txtField.tag == 10) {
                        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"customNames"]) {
                            txtField.text = [names objectAtIndex:4]; }
                        else {
                            txtField.text = @"Iseland";
                        }
                    }
                    if (txtField.tag == 11) {
                        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"customNames"]) {
                            txtField.text = [names objectAtIndex:5]; }
                        else {
                            txtField.text = @"Player";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        [self saveNames];
    }
```

Edit: I've received an answer elsewhere and it greatly reduces the length as well as making it more readable:

```
NSArray *defaultNames = @[@"Peter", @"Julia",...];
int offsetIndex = 6;
BOOl needCustomNames = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"customNames"];
for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) 
    {
        UITextField *txtField = (UITextField *)view;
        int index = [txtField tag]-offsetIndex;
        if (txtField.tag >= 6 && txtField.tag <= 11)
        {
            if (needCustomNames)
                txtField.text = [names objectAtIndex:index];
            else
                txtField.text = [defaultNames objectAtIndex:index];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jamal: I'm not sure your modified title is an improvement in this case. The original title made it clear that the OP was worried about the `if` structure of the code.  That point is pretty well hidden now.

Comment: @GraniteRobert: I've made the title reflect the purpose of the code, which is what we prefer here as titles would otherwise be very generic.  I have added that request to the post body, which I should've done before.

Comment: @DaleTownsend Please "Accept" an answer if it helped you write better code. This will help others find the best answer in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can do better still.

First of all, we're talking about a `UITableViewCell` to which you've added custom views--or at least modified existing views (hence the tags) as well as adding a gesture recognizer.

What makes most sense is to instead subclass `UITableViewCell`.  This would help both to clean up the method you have posted here as well as clean up the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` which I'm sure is a bit of a mess.

Then, you would no longer need to iterate through all of the content view's subviews.  Instead, best case scenario, you only have a single text field on the cell, and you can access it directly, and `switch` on its tag, and at worst, you can create a custom IBCollection--an array of text fields--that would be relevant to this method and iterate over just that (which you know would contain only text fields relevant to this method) looking at the tags.

---

```
int index = [txtField tag]-offsetIndex;
if (tag >= 6 && tag <= 11)
{
    if (needCustomNames)
        textField.text = [names objectAtIndex:index];
    else
        textField.text = [defaultNames objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

This chunk of code is confusing.

First of all, `tag` isn't declared anywhere.

Second of all, presuming the `if` is supposed to be checking `textField.tag`, you should either move the `int index` line inside the if block, or probably better, refactor the if to check the `index` that was just calculated based on `textField.tag` and is the value actually used inside the `if` block.  As it stands, this code might crash if someone unknowingly changes the `offsetIndex` 7 lines previously and that might be a hard crash to figure out.

---

I think there's some more cleanup to do, but I'm kind of interested in seeing whether you'd be interested in posting a new question where you've rewritten the code to use a `UITableViewCell` subclass, which truly would be the best option.